# Android Service multiple instances

Tags: android, service, instance

Im still a bit new to the Android Service Class.  I know you need to start the service from your application with startService(intent), however my problem is my service has methods inside it.  I need to start the service with an intent and then create an object of that class in my Activity so I can call methods of the service.  The problem is when I do this I create one instance of the service when I start it with an intent and another instance of the service when I create an object of the class in my activity.  This means any data passed to the service from startService(intent) is not there when I create the object of the service.  Any ways around this or am I just totally misusing the service class?  I can give some code but its basically this:

```
//Create Object of ControlPanel service class.
ControlPanel cPanel = new ControlPanel();
//Create intent for starting ControlPanel service class
Intent controlPanel = new Intent(this, cPanel.getClass());
//Start Service
startService(controlPanel);
```

Answer (score 20):

I'd say you are misusing the class :-).

Calling startService() multiple times does not result in starting multiple service.

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29):

> Request that a given application service be started. The Intent can either contain the complete class name of a specific service implementation to start, or an abstract definition through the action and other fields of the kind of service to start. If this service is not already running, it will be instantiated and started (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running.

You should override [onStartCommand()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) as well. The first startService call starts the service if it has not been started yet. In any case onStartCommand will intercept any further startService calls and the intent you want to send to it.

Answer (score 9):

> Any ways around this or am I just totally misusing the service class?

You are totally misusing the `Service` class.

A `Service` is used via two basic patterns:

1. Sending commands to it, via `startService()`.
2. Binding to it, to call an API exposed by that `Service`, via `bindService()`.

Binding more accurately depicts what you are trying to do ("so I can call methods of the service"), however binding is tricky to get right, particularly when it comes to configuration changes.

Hence, I would recommend first that you sit back and determine **completely and precisely *why*** you are using a `Service` in the first place. `ControlPanel`, for example, is a name I would associate with a UI, not UI-less ("background") operations. Then and only then can you determine if the command or the binding pattern is appropriate for your use case.

Comment: I will look into bindService().  I read over it briefly before but never had a use for it.  Ill see what I can find about it.  Any good tutorial pages you could recommend?

Comment: @TravisElliott: "Any good tutorial pages you could recommend?" -- I am sure that there are some, but I do not know of any off the top of my head. My simplest sample is https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AdvServices/Binding but it is from an advanced chapter of my book and therefore assumes experience with other stuff, like fragments.

Comment: The whole point of doing this is I need the service to perform work when I call a method of it, then send info back via a messenger to the main activity.  The service has a runnable thread in it that performs work on a background thread(sending data via tcp socket).  Any idea on a better way to do this.  I really dont want to use an Intent service because another thread needs to stay running as well for receiving data.

Comment: @TravisElliott: "Any idea on a better way to do this" -- just send commands to the service via `startService()`, and have it use the `Messenger` as you state. "I really dont want to use an Intent service because another thread needs to stay running as well for receiving data." -- agreed, `IntentService` is not designed for long-lived threads like this.

Answer (score -8):

You can do this with one service class.

```
public static int myStaticMethod(){
        return 1;
    }
```

Simply make the methods you need to access static.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question.