# Running multiple instance of a service

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

Is it possible to start a service multiple times. Means calling startService multiple times. I know if I call  `startService` , it'll call `onCreate() -> onStartCommand()`. on `startService`, it calls only `onStartCommand()` without `onCreate()`. What happens to the service ? Is it creating multiple instance of the service ?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876745/how-to-have-multiple-instance-of-service-in-android) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931462/android-service-multiple-instances) links for more details

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the Service will only run in one instance. However, every time you start the service, the onStartCommand() method is called. Look at [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService).